# Is it necessary to uninstall rubygems-update?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I was reading the *Agile Web Development with Rails* book the other day. The author issues the following command to update rubygems:

```
gem update --system
gem uninstall rubygems-update
```

Why is it necessary/good-practice to uninstall rubygems-update after updating rubygems?

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely not necessary to uninstall `rubygems-update`, as your rubygems functionality will function fine with it still installed.  It's optional/nice to do because it is only used for updating rubygems, and thus after rubygems has been updated the `rubygems-update` gem is simply an extra file and takes up space on your computer and shows up when you run `gem list` unnecessarily.